# Join n outlook items into one new object with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, search, outlook, office-automation

I am looking for emails from person x in n outlook folders in Excel with VBA. What I want to do is find the most recent item of the n results (or of more folders).

I considered merging the n objects, sort by `ReceivedTime` and then get the top item, but I can't manage merging them, or find the most recent of the n objects.

Example is for 2 folders, 2 items:

```
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFldr As Outlook.Folder 'to be the inbox
    Dim olArchive As Outlook.Folder 'my archive folder
    Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim olArchiveItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim i As Long
    Dim emailStr As String
    Dim filter As String
    Dim olSentFldr as Outlook.Folder

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' olFolderInbox
    Set olArchive = olNs.Folders(CStr(olNs.Accounts.Item(1)))
    
   Set olSentFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

       emailStr = "somebody@outlook.com"
         
        filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = """ & emailStr & """"
        Set olItems = olFldr.Items.Restrict(filter)
        Set olArchiveItems = olArchive.Items.Restrict(filter)
    
        olItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
        olArchiveItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
        olSentFldr.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True


    Dim olNew as Object 
   
` below hypothetical solution that does not work yet--------------
    olNew = merge(olItems(1), olArchiveItems(1))
    olNew.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
    myOutcome = olNew(1)
```

Comment: At the first glance I can observe a typo: `Set olArchiveItems = olCleanUp.Items.Restrict(filter)`.  I cannot see where `olCleanUp` has been set. It probably should be replace with `olArchive`. It is good to have `Option Explicit` on top of the module keeping the code. It will warn you for such a typo. Now, you did not explain what your code does against what you need...

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want suggesting that your code as it is (without the typo) should work. For instance, `Debug.Print olItems(1).ReceivedTime, olItems(olItems.count).ReceivedTime` will return the last and the first received mail...

Comment: Corrected the typo and I'm using option explicit . I want to join the 1st item of all my searched folders into 1 new item, and then sort by received time, and then grab item 1 of the new item, see comment at bottom of my code

Comment: But, not need of any merge, I think... You should only put the two folders first item in two variables (`olItD as Date, olArchD As Date`) and then only compare them. `If olItD > olArchD Then` `Debug.Print olItD` `Else` `Debug.Print olArchD`...

Comment: Of course to set the mail... It was only a suggestion to test that it works. You cannot use this solution for more than one mail account. You will never know which of them is the last one. If by "items" you mean **folders**, you may place the results in two arrays and then try matching the maximum Date and return the correspondent object/mail.

Comment: Anyhow, you cannot merge more such folders. If I remember well, it is an `AdvancedSearch` method accepting more folders, but when I tried it, sometimes it returned well and other times not. I never could understand why. I remember something about an Outlook event (`AdvancedSearchComplete`) which is triggered and the result must be used only after/if it has been triggered...

Comment: I have changed the code in my question again to illustrate better what 'item' or 'object' i am trying to grab and join so that I can sort by receiveddate. Looking for a solution that will work also for more than 2 'items'

Comment: You need to `AdvancedSearch` method of the Outlook `Application` class instead. See my post for more information.

Comment: I tried digging deeper and succeeded to obtain some pieces of code able to search in two Outlook folders (at once), working togeteher and using `AdvancedSearch`. It is not so complicated to use it inside Outlook (VBA), but a real challenge to automate Outlook form Excel. I mean, Outlook has a specific event being triggered when the search finished (`AdvancedSearchComplete`). It can be easily to change the value of a boolean variable, but in is not so easy to read its value from outside Outlook. So, I found a way to access Excel module and change there such a variable.

Comment: Outlook needs the mentioned event to have some specific code, able to call a sub from Excel module where the automation works. If the code will try saving the search folder **before the search is confirmed as finished**, the folder will be empty. Of course, Outlook must be open as **Macro Enabled**, to let the event working and its Excel automation doing what is needed. If interested, I can try assembling the pieces of code I played with and post a working answer. I can see that you already accepted an answer putting in practice my above suggestion. The offered variant does it what you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare search results.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub mostRecentItem_MultipleSearches()

    ' Early Binding - requires reference to Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.namespace
    
    Dim olFldr As Outlook.Folder 'to be the inbox
    Dim olSentFldr As Outlook.Folder
    
    Dim olFldrItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim olSentFldrItems As Outlook.Items
    
    Dim olItemRecent As Object
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim emailStr As String
    Dim filter As String
    
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' valid with early binding
    Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)   ' 6 if late binding
    Set olFldrItems = olFldr.Items
    Debug.Print "olFldrItems.count: " & olFldrItems.count
    
    emailStr = "somebody@outlook.com"
    filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = """ & emailStr & """"
    
    olFldrItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
    Set olFldrItems = olFldrItems.Restrict(filter)
    Debug.Print "olFldrItems.count: " & olFldrItems.count
    
    Set olItemRecent = olFldrItems(1)
    'olItemRecent.Display
    
    Set olSentFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set olSentFldrItems = olSentFldr.Items
    olSentFldrItems.Sort "[SentOn]", True
    
    Debug.Print "olSentFldrItems.count: " & olSentFldrItems.count
    
    Debug.Print olItemRecent.ReceivedTime
    Debug.Print olSentFldrItems(1).SentOn
    
    If olItemRecent.ReceivedTime < olSentFldrItems(1).SentOn Then
         Set olItemRecent = olSentFldrItems(1)
    End If
    
    olItemRecent.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: Only in your answer there is no filter for sent to address on the sent items folder so I'll just get the most recent email to anyone right?

Comment: the `Sent.on` is indeed the correction I needed for sorting the sent items. thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to Sort collection before running the `Restrict` of `Find`/`FindNext` methods if you want to get items ordered.

```
olItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
olArchiveItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
olSentFldr.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = """ & emailStr & """"
Set olItems = olItems.Restrict(filter)
Set olArchiveItems = olArchiveItems.Restrict(filter)
```

Try using not a straight comparison in the search string:

```
filter = Chr(34) & "[SenderEmailAddress]" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & emailStr &"'"`
```

It looks like you need to use the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class which performs a search based on a specified DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) search string. You can run the search in multiple folders at once. So, there is no need to run the search separately for each folder:

```
Set olItems = olFldr.Items.Restrict(filter)
Set olArchiveItems = olArchive.Items.Restrict(filter)
```

You can run it once for all folders and the search is performed in the background. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about the `AdvancedSearch` method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Comment: instead of spamming your article on a lot of questions, which is by far to complex to grasp for low-level coders, I suggest you actually give a working example based on the questions. I would love to learn using advanced search, but i am utterly lost how to search for instance my 'sent items' box, or an inbox filter based on a string with an email address.

Comment: I've updated the post with required changes in the search string. The article explains how the `AdvancedSearch` works and provides a sample code which you could use as a starting point. It is not reasonable to include all that information in a single post here.

Comment: My search function already worked just fine. What I'm asking is how to combine the individual search results to sort by date to identify the most recent one of all search results

Comment: In case of `AdavancedSearch` you just need to specify folders where to search. The results will be combined into a single piece. So, the task is solved already.

Comment: And if you want to get results in a specific order you need to `Sort` items before.

Comment: does advancedsearch allow searching the sent items box based on an email address by any chance?

Comment: The same rules apply to the search criteria.